# Access VBA - Opening a Form after Closing Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access database where I created a Main Menu to Open a table then closed the main menu.  I'm having issue when the table is closed I need to open the main menu form, and I'm not sure where to put the vba code.

Comment: And the $64 million dollar question: why close the Main Menu? Tables and queries are not user interface objects and normally are not opened directly for the user. Consider using a datasheet form of table.

Comment: I have the table to load.  The step process is the main menu load then the user click the button to load the table to edit. The main menu is closed when the table load. When the user close the table I want the main menu to open again to select.  Because if I don't close the main menu and the table opens the main menu is in the front of the table.

Comment: Once again use a datasheet bound to table and then you will have a VBA event to use. Datasheets can look very similar to tables.

Comment: what @Parfait said, unless for some reason the user needs to be able to edit the structure of the table. Which would be pretty unusual, and personally I'd rather give the user an interface of dialog boxes walking them through set kinds of table alterations to keep it limited, rather than let someone who may or may not know what they're doing have virtually direct and unlimited access/permissions on the raw data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait) said in the comments, giving the user direct access to the table itself is rarely a good idea. I'd recommend creating a datasheet version of the table so they can view the data in a table-like layout.

Specifically, you want to create a form that defaults to datasheet view. There are many ways to do this, but the easiest way in Access 2010 is to open the table you wish to link to, and in the forms group of the Create tab, click "more forms" and then "datasheet".

All you need to do then is save the table, and then link to *that* with the button on your main menu, instead of the original table. You won't need to close the main menu, as it'll hide behind the new form, and closing the new form will reveal it again behind.